# Override Series.Add() in Custom Chart Class

Tags: c#, charts

I have created a class as follows:

```
public class clsCustomSeriesCollection:SeriesCollection
    {
        //  Want to divert the .series.add to be series.add, then formatting
        public clsCustomSeriesCollection()
        {
            //  No constructor contains x arguments here what ever x is
        }
    }
public class clsCustomChart : Chart
{
    public clsCustomChart()
        {
        this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        this.ResetAutoValues();
        this.Series.Clear();
        // More formatting
        }
}
```

Where the constructor has all the relevant formatting that i require.  I would also like to have a custom series type, every time a series is added, it's formatting is also looked after.

I have tried to create a derrived custom series collection, but get constructor argument issues there.

So when i do `.Series.Add("Series1")` from the form where the chart resides and then populate data points, i want the series to be of this custom type.

Many thanks

Nathan.

Comment: Can you show us some more code (particularly the part that's causing your problem, as this constructor looks fine)?

Comment: @Timmeh sure, i'll update, but the question is more of how to create a custom seriescollection and all series' added to be of a particular format